# Code doesn't go through when inputting a number when prompted

Tags: java, user-input

I'm a beginner to Java, the code is for a homework assignment regarding files and loops.
When I to run this code to check for any errors, when hitting a number, it doesn't go forward past the menu. However, if I hit 5, it then start's with the choice that's meant for 1. I'm not exactly sure what's happening that's resulting in the error.

I did try to switch the code to a switch method instead of a while loop, but that resulted in just the code not moving forward regardless of what option was selected. I also tried moving scanners around but that didn't also effect it.

The following is the code for reference

```
Import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;


public class Homework3A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    { 
        
        //Homework3A
        //Lance Torres, completed on DATE
        
                
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1. Add student\n"
                + "2. Add course \n"
                + "3. Display student\n"
                + "4. Display Course.\n"
                + "5. Exit"); //the message that will display to start the menu 
         
        int menuChoice = userInput.nextInt(); //changing the scanner type into a int type for the menu loop 
        //will be using a while loop for this since it is a loop i am more familiar with when typing menus 
        PrintWriter StudentOPFile = new PrintWriter("Students.txt");
        PrintWriter CoursesOPFile = new PrintWriter("Courses.txt"); 
        while (menuChoice != 5); //this loop will keep happening until the user hits the int 5  
        { 
            if (menuChoice == 1); //for adding a student 
            { 
                Scanner studentInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
                System.out.println("Please enter the new Student ID. "); 
                System.out.println("Student ID: "); 
                int studentID = studentInput.nextInt();
                //the system message and the string that will collect the user ID 
                
                System.out.println("Please enter the Student's first name: "); 
                String firstName = studentInput.nextLine(); 
                //code above is for when the user enters the first name of the student 
                
                System.out.println("Please enter the Student's last name: "); 
                String lastName = studentInput.nextLine(); //for the last name of the student 
                
                System.out.println("Please enter the address: "); 
                String address = studentInput.nextLine(); 
                //for the address 
                
                System.out.println("Please enter the city: "); 
                String city = studentInput.nextLine(); 
                //for the city 
                
                System.out.println("Please enter the state"); 
                String state = studentInput.nextLine(); 
                //for the state 
                
                FileWriter StudentWriter = new FileWriter("Students.txt", true); //adding a file writer in order to append information to the file
                PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(StudentWriter);
                outputFile.println(studentID + firstName + lastName + address + city + state); //adds all the information as a line 
                outputFile.close(); //closes the file 
                System.out.println("Student information added successfully."); //system display message when the system finishes writing it to file 
                }
                
            }
            if (menuChoice == 2); 
            { 
                Scanner courseInput = new Scanner(System.in) ;
                System.out.println("Please enter the course ID: ");
                int courseID = courseInput.nextInt(); 
                //for when the user adds the courseID 
                
                System.out.println("Please enter the course name: "); 
                String courseName = courseInput.nextLine(); 
                //when the user adds the course's name 
                
                System.out.println("Please enter a decription for the course: "); 
                String courseDescrption = courseInput.nextLine(); 
                //when the user adds the descrption, decided to make this a string as well since it could be a long sentence as opposed to a single world 
                
                FileWriter CourseWriter = new FileWriter("Courses.txt", true); 
                PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(CourseWriter);
                outputFile.println(courseID + courseName + courseDescrption);
                outputFile.close(); 
                System.out.println("Course information added successfully.");
            } 
            if (menuChoice == 3);
            { 
                 File studentFile = new File("Students.txt");
                 Scanner inputFileusingStudentID = new Scanner(studentFile); 
                 while (inputFileusingStudentID.hasNext())
                     {
                     String studentInformation = inputFileusingStudentID.nextLine(); 
                     
                     System.out.println(studentInformation); 
                     }
                 inputFileusingStudentID.close(); 
            }
            if (menuChoice == 4); 
            { 
                 File coursesFile = new File("Courses.txt");
                 Scanner inputFileusingCourseID = new Scanner(coursesFile); 
                 while (inputFileusingCourseID.hasNext())
                     {
                     String courseInformation = inputFileusingCourseID.nextLine(); 
                     
                     System.out.println(courseInformation); 
                     }
                 inputFileusingCourseID.close(); 
            } System.out.println("Thank you for using the program. Now Exiting...");
            System.out.println("Goodbye."); 
        }   
    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Comment: Does your code really start with `Import java.util.Scanner;`? Because that won't compile, Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo  It could be at least a *part* of your problem.

Comment: you have this > `;`  on the while and in all ifs ex: `(menuChoice != 5);`  and what it should be `(menuChoice != 5)`

Comment: See the dupe to get an answer to your current issue. Then see the question @PM77-1 has linked to, this is also an issue in your code. And you never ask the user for another menu item when the first item has been processed.